# SQL return maximum for groupby

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following database with 4 tables: `scores`, `players`, `games`, `levels`.

```
CREATE TABLE games(
   gameid     INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,name   VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
  ,active VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (gameid)
);

INSERT INTO games(gameid,name,active) VALUES (1,'pang','yes');
INSERT INTO games(gameid,name,active) VALUES (2,'pong','yes');
INSERT INTO games(gameid,name,active) VALUES (3,'pung','yes');

CREATE TABLE levels(
   levelid     INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,name   VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
  ,active VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (levelid)

);
INSERT INTO levels(levelid,name,active) VALUES (1,'pang','yes');
INSERT INTO levels(levelid,name,active) VALUES (2,'pong','yes');
INSERT INTO levels(levelid,name,active) VALUES (3,'pung','yes');

CREATE TABLE player(
   playerid     INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,name   VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
  ,surname VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (playerid)

);
INSERT INTO player(playerid,name,surname) VALUES (1,'pang','yes');
INSERT INTO player(playerid,name,surname) VALUES (2,'pong','yes');
INSERT INTO player(playerid,name,surname) VALUES (3,'pung','yes');



CREATE TABLE scores (
    gameid int NOT NULL,
    levelid int NOT NULL,
    playerid int NOT NULL,
    score int NOT NULL

);

INSERT INTO scores(gameID,levelID, playerID, score) VALUES (1,1,1,50);
INSERT INTO scores(gameID,levelID, playerID, score) VALUES (1,1,2,60);
INSERT INTO scores(gameID,levelID, playerID, score) VALUES (1,1,3,100);
INSERT INTO scores(gameID,levelID, playerID, score) VALUES (2,1,2,60);
INSERT INTO scores(gameID,levelID, playerID, score) VALUES (2,1,3,500);
```

I'm trying to return the player with the topic score for each level of each game. At the moment, I can't seem to figure out why I'm reassigning the max score to each player. My code is the following:

```
SELECT g.gameid, l.levelid, p.playerid, ts.top_score
FROM scores s
INNER JOIN games g ON g.gameid = s.gameid
INNER JOIN levels l ON l.levelid = s.levelid
INNER JOIN player p ON p.playerid = s.playerid

INNER JOIN (
  SELECT gameID, levelid, MAX(score) AS top_score FROM scores GROUP BY gameid, levelid
  ) ts ON (s.gameid = ts.gameid AND s.levelid = ts.levelid)

GROUP BY g.gameid, l.levelid, p.playerid, ts.top_score
```

DB fiddle available: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/peyKD96aPmZTjY1MSn1ik2/4

Desired output is:

```
gameid, levelid, playerid, score 
  1,       1,      3,       100
  2,       1,      3,       500
```

Comment: show us your desired output as well

Comment: @eshirvana added desired output

Comment: ok then my answer is correct, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly , you want this :

```
select g.gameid, l.levelid, p.playerid, s.score 
from (
  select * , row_number() over (partition by gameid,levelid order by score desc) rn 
  from scores
) s 
join games g on s.gameId = g.gameid
join levels l on l.levelid = s.levelid
join player p on p.playerid = s.playerid
where s.rn = 1;
```

however If you are not selecting any columns from l,p or g, you really don't need to join with those tables at all

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to use the partition approach to find the top within each group. There’s a good explanation here : http://www.silota.com/docs/recipes/sql-top-n-group.html

Answer (score 0):

Same soluntion as that of @eshirvana, but it uses Rank() - If multiple players have same max score,it list all of them.

```
WITH RANKING(gameid,levelid,playerid,score,rn) AS
 (
   select gameid,levelid,playerid,score, 
          Rank() over (partition by gameid,levelid order by score desc) rn 
     from scores
 )
 select gameid,levelid,playerid,score from ranking where rn=1
```